# ArcGIS Server Error - ClientCommunicatorAdmin restart

Tags: arcgis-server, java, error

I am seeing some strange behavior each night with our ArcGIS Sever installation where it will throw the following error and become unresponsive.

```
Sep 01, 2014 4:03:06 AM ClientCommunicatorAdmin restart
WARNING: Failed to restart: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.30.14; nested exception is:
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Sep 01, 2014 4:03:27 AM RMIConnector RMIClientCommunicatorAdmin-doStop
WARNING: Failed to call the method close():java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.30.14; nested exception is:
  java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Sep 01, 2014 4:03:27 AM ClientCommunicatorAdmin Checker-run
WARNING: Failed to check connection: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
Sep 01, 2014 4:03:27 AM ClientCommunicatorAdmin Checker-run
WARNING: stopping
```

I am still able to navigate to the the manager page, however, each service is listed as "stopping" or "stopped". Restarting the service for ArcGIS Server seems to resolve the problem until approximately the same time on the next day

We have tried re-installing but the problem is still reoccurring..

Has anyone run into this problem before and, if so, what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: is the host: 192.168.30.14 on the same domain (likely)? http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0154000004qt000000